# MsAdalAngular6Service - Handle Invalid Logins

Tags: angular, typescript, azure-active-directory

I have an Angular 7 application using the `ms-adal-angular6` library and am trying to determine my code flow.

I am properly authenticating to AAD with a user who is currently logged in with their AAD account.  I get a fully populated MsAdalAngular6Service variable with all properties filled in.

Where in this process do I determine if the login failed?   My code is as follows:

```
 export class AppComponent {

    constructor(private adalSvc: MsAdalAngular6Service) {

    var token = this.adalSvc.acquireToken('http://adal.resource.com').subscribe((token: string) => {            
       // This works fine for pre-logged in users, token is valid
    });

    }
 }
```

Where am I supposed to check if this entire process "failed"?   We are using a mix of individual user accounts as well as Azure AD and if the user does not pass the Azure AD process they need to get re-directed to the IUA process.

Do I just check if this returned token is valid?   At this point, `adalSvc` has full user information if they user has already been logged in to Azure AD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When authenticating with AAD, the process is handled independently in "AAD portal", instead  of your website. When login is successful, AD portal will redirect to "redirect url" you set with valid token.

But if login failed, an error page like below appears and it will NOT redirect:

[image]

Besides, this page is not allowed to customized. So you can't put another login link or some notification for user in here.

Regarding your requirement, a good practice is to provide a page for users to choose to login from AAD or with their individual accounts. 
In `ms-adal-angular6`, you can set `popUp:true` then the login page will appear in pop-up window, not a new page. When login failed, the user just needs to close the window then choose another login method.